# Question regarding proof of Fatou's lemma

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm really confused with the step enclosed in red. Can someone please be kind enough to explain to me why does it follow the part in red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X^+$ is the set of $x$ on which $\varphi(x)>0$ and $X^0$ is the set on which $\varphi(x)=0$. Then

$$\int_E\overline\varphi dm = \int_{E\cap X^+}(\varphi(x)-\varepsilon) dm + \int_{E\cap X^0} \varphi(x) dm \,.$$

The first integral breaks into $\int_{E\cap X^+}\varphi dm - \int_{E\cap X^+}\varepsilon\, dm$. The second integral is then combined back into the first part of this and since $(E\cap X^+)\cup (E\cap X^0)=E$, you get the domain back that you want. Then treat $\varepsilon$ as a simple function, do the integration, and the equality follows.

Comment: why does it break like this the first integral? Can you explain ?

Comment: why does $\int_E (f+g)dm = \int_E f dm + \int_E g dm$ ? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: does $E = \{ x : \phi \geq 0 \} $ ??

Comment: i havent yet proved this in my book so i cannot use it i guess :/

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit sloppy with my thoughts for $E^0$ and $E^+$, when they are proper subsets of the measure space you have to do this sort of dancing around. I edited my question, it should be right now. As for the splitting the integral thing; you can do this on your own from the definition. In fact, if the book does not prove this explicitly, it's probably left as an exercise :)

Comment: does $X^+ \subseteq E $ ??

Comment: No. I use the notation suggestively: $X$ is the whole space, so of course $E\subseteq X$, and $X^+\subseteq X$ is meant to make you think that this is all points in $X$ that are positive in that sense. But there need be no relation between $X^+$ and $E$

Comment: OK, but then when integrating $\epsilon$ as a simple function, we obtain: $\epsilon m( X^+ \cap E) $ how is $m( X^+ \cap E) = M(X^+) $ ?

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Oh, that's interesting. I guess your book defines $E=X$ because you're right: the set it gives is what I call $X^+$ but in general that is clearly wrong: Let $\varphi=1$ on the left half of the unit square, zero on the right half, let $E$ be the upper half. Then $X^+$ is the left half and the left integral is $1/4-1/4\epsilon$, but the difference is $1/4-1/2\epsilon$.

Comment: So $\int_E \overline{\phi} = \int_E \phi + \epsilon m(E)$ ?

Comment: No, that fails my example also, for the exact same values. You cannot say more than $\int_E \overline{\varphi} = \int_E \varphi - \epsilon m(E\cap X^+)$, or in the language of the book, $\int_E \overline{\varphi} = \int_E \varphi - \epsilon m(\{x\in E: \varphi(x)>0\})$

Comment: but how does it follow that $\int_{E \cap X^+} \phi = \int_E \phi ?$

Comment: then can you explain how do you get the expression in your previous comment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11191/discussion-between-eric-stucky-and-don-anselmo)